# Правило для POST запроса в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Методом POST отправляется переменная с названием var1 или var2

Если одна из этих 2 переменных в запросе присутствует, перенаправить на alarm.php .

Соответственно если эти переменные отправлены методом GET или их нет в POST должно действовать дефолтное поведение.

Answer (score 1):

Apache не позволяет добраться до тела запроса, а значит прямой ответ на поставленный вопрос:
Это невозможно.

Однако можно перенаправлять все POST запросы одному скрипту и уже в нем средствами PHP определять наличие нужных переменных.

```
RewriteCond REQUEST_METHOD ^POST$
```

---

Если очень-очень хочется это реализовать, то придется сменить Apache на nginx.
Nginx позволяет сделать это с помощью встраиваемого LUA и функции [get_post_args](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.req.get_post_args).

Answer (score 0):

Обязательно .htaccess и mod_rewrite?

Как-нибудь вот так нельзя что ли? :) Например, на PHP. :)

```
if (isset($_POST['var1']) || isset($_POST['var2'])) {

header ("Location: /alarm.php"); exit;

}
```

Или какой там волшебный язык используется? :)

Comment: Нет. Я не знаю к какому php файлу CMS будет запрос.

Comment: @fStrange дык если нет второго параметра вы и напишите что-то типа

    if (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) $path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($path=="") $path="index";
    include $path.".php";

Comment: @eicto
Повторяю. Я не знаю к какому из тысяч php файлов будет запрос. Вы предлагаете мне исправить всю эту тысячу файлов?

Comment: а rewrite вам на что, вы все запросы с методом POST отправляйте на враппер...

    RewriteCond REQUEST_METHOD ^POST$